# Embedded DWG in RVT 3D View not Displaying Correctly in Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I've imported a DWG file into the 3D view of a RVT model, and am trying to convert and view it in the Forge Viewer. When I view that 3D view in the Forge Viewer the drawing does not display correctly. See links to screenshots below.

I've looked through the response JSON from Model Derivative and do not see any errors.

The RVT project file and the DWG I am trying to embed are also linked below. I am using the rac_basic_sample_project file, where I exported the site plan view to a DWG, and tried to embed that into the default {3D} view.

[3D View in Revit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mv645.jpg)

[3D View in Forge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y97a5.jpg)

[RVT File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/g8mt3ybges3nepi/mod_rac_basic_sample_project.rvt?dl=0)

[DWG File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vnp9n2lf9zr3oug/rac_basic_sample_project%20-%20Floor%20Plan%20-%20Site.dwg?dl=0)

Comment: You should provide your [mcve] as copyable, searchable text as an [edit].

Comment: By `import` did you import the DWG to your rvt model and then translate the result? Or did you load/aggregate the DWG onto the rvt model on Viewer?

Comment: Thanks @jdv I will put that together.

Comment: @BryanHuang the former. I imported the DWG into the rvt model and then translated the result.

Comment: Can you try aggregate the DWG into the rvt model following steps [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/preparing-your-viewing-application-multi-model-workflows)?. If you would us to look into the issue with the imports pls email to forge.help@autodesk.com with a brief description of the issue and include download link for the model files (can use a service such as [weTransfer](https://wetransfer.com)